# Detect if a SingleChildScrollview/Listview can be scrolled

Tags: flutter, dart

So, i have a widget with infinite width (Row) . To fill the widget with items i'm using a Lisview builder with Axis horizontal. I also can use a SingleChildScrollview with axis horizontal and a Row as the child.

If there is a few items, the width of the screen is not filled, so that's great. However, when there is a lot of items, the Listview becomes "scrollable" , and i can scroll to the right to reveal the items.

I would like to know if the list is scrollable (if it overflows). The purpose is to show a little text saying "Scroll to reveal more>>".

I know i can use maths and calculate the items width with the screen width. However... The Listview already knows this, so i was wondering if there was a way of getting access to that information

Comment: As a workaround i could check if the last item is rendered and hide the text if it is. However that's not the answer to the question. So i will leave it open for now.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem. I found this solution here: [Determine Scroll Widget height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57762436/determine-scroll-widget-height)

Here's my question in case it's helpful: [How do you tell if scrolling is not needed in a SingleChildScrollView when the screen is first built?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65010791/how-do-you-tell-if-scrolling-is-not-needed-in-a-singlechildscrollview-when-the-s)

**Solution:**

1. Import the scheduler Flutter library:

```
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
```

2. Create a boolean flag inside the state object but outside of the `build` method to track whether `build` has been called yet:

```
bool buildCalledYet = false;
```

3. Create a boolean `isScrollable` variable inside the state object but outside of the `build` method:

```
bool isScrollable;
```

4. Add the following in the beginning of the `build` method:

```
if (!firstBuild) {
      firstBuild = true;
      SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        setState(() {
          isScrollable = !(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent > 0);
        });
      });
    }
```

(The purpose of `buildCalledYet` is to prevent this code from causing `build` to be called over and over again.)

5. If `isScrollable` is `true`, then show your text.

Answer (score 1):

I created a widget called **ScrollCheckerWidget** with a `controller` property to pass the controller of a scrollable widget and check if it is scrollable in the view. The **ScrollCheckerWidget** widget has a `builder` callback function where you can return a widget and use the `isScrollable` boolean from the `builder` to check if the widget related to the controller is scrollable or not. Here you have the code:

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScrollCheckerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScrollCheckerWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.controller,
    required this.builder,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final ScrollController controller;
  final Widget Function(bool isScrollable) builder;

  @override
  State<ScrollCheckerWidget> createState() => _ScrollCheckerWidgetState();
}

class _ScrollCheckerWidgetState extends State<ScrollCheckerWidget> {
  late final ScrollController _scrollController;
  late bool _isScrollable;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController = widget.controller;

    _isScrollable = false;

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      setState(() {
        _isScrollable = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent > 0;
      });
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.builder.call(_isScrollable);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In builder:

```
return NotificationListener(
            onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
              print("ScrollStartNotification");
              // add your logic here
            },
            child: SingleChildScrollView(...
```

Am trying to detect exact same thing myself, wrapping SingleChildScrollView with NotificationListener at least gave me a point of reference to start working on this.

Answer (score 0):

bool get isScrollable => scrollController.position.extentInside > 0;