# How do you tell if scrolling is not needed in a SingleChildScrollView when the screen is first built?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `SingleChildScrollView`. Sometimes its `child` is longer than the screen, in which case the `SingleChildScrollView` lets you scroll. But also sometimes its `child` is shorter than the screen, in which case no scrolling is needed.

I am trying to add an arrow to the bottom of the screen which hints to the user that they can/should scroll down to see the rest of the contents. I successfully implemented this except in the case where the `child` of the `SingleChildScrollView` is shorter than the screen. In this case no scrolling is needed, so I would like to not show the arrow at all.

I've tried making a `listener` to do this, but the `listener` isn't activated until you start scrolling, and in this case you can't scroll.

I've also tried accessing the properties of the `_scrollController` in the ternary operator which shows the arrow, but an exception is thrown: `ScrollController not attached to any scroll views.`

Here is a complete sample app showing what I'm doing, so you can just copy and paste it if you want to see it run. I replaced all of the contents with a `Column` of `Text` widgets for simplicity:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: MyScreen()));
}

class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyScreenState createState() => _MyScreenState();
}

class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  bool atBottom = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Activated when you get to the bottom:
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.extentAfter == 0) {
        setState(() {
          atBottom = true;
        });
      }
    });

    // Activated as soon as you start scrolling back up after getting to the bottom:
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.extentAfter > 0 && atBottom) {
        setState(() {
          atBottom = false;
        });
      }
    });

    // I want this to activate if you are at the top of the screen and there is
    // no scrolling to do, i.e. the widget being displayed fits in the screen:
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.offset == 0 &&
          _scrollController.position.extentAfter == 0) {
        setState(() {
          atBottom = false;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                  Text(
                    i.toString(),
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        atBottom
            ? Container()
            : Positioned(
                bottom: 10,
                right: 10,
                child: Container(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_circle_down,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Import the scheduler Flutter library:

```
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
```

2. Create a boolean flag inside the state object but outside of the `build` method to track whether `build` has been called yet:

```
bool buildCalledYet = false;
```

3. Add the following in the beginning of the `build` method:

```
if (!firstBuild) {
      firstBuild = true;
      SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        setState(() {
          atBottom = !(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent > 0);
        });
      });
    }
```

(The boolean flag prevents this code from causing `build` to be called over and over again.)

Here's the complete code of the sample app implementing this solution:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: MyScreen()));
}

class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyScreenState createState() => _MyScreenState();
}

class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  bool atBottom = false;
  // ======= new code =======
  bool buildCalledYet = false;
  // ========================

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.extentAfter == 0) {
        setState(() {
          atBottom = true;
        });
      }
    });

    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.extentAfter > 0 && atBottom) {
        setState(() {
          atBottom = false;
        });
      }
    });

    // ======= The third listener is not needed. =======
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // =========================== new code ===========================
    if (!buildCalledYet) {
      buildCalledYet = true;
      SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        setState(() {
          atBottom = !(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent > 0);
        });
      });
    }
    // ================================================================

    return Stack(
      children: [
        SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                  Text(
                    i.toString(),
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        atBottom
            ? Container()
            : Positioned(
                bottom: 10,
                right: 10,
                child: Container(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_circle_down,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I found this solution on another Stack Overflow question: [Determine Scroll Widget height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57762436/determine-scroll-widget-height)